# How to call multiple functions in order one after another as long as the previous is complete

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to call 3 functions in order but each function needs to have been completed before the next should run. Each function has a completion handler that calls another function upon completion. After reading lots online about dispatch queues I though this may be the best way to approach it, that's if I am understanding it correctly of course. When I run my code Each function is called in order but not when the previous has been completed. In the first function I am downloading an image from firebase but the second function gets called before the image has downloaded. I've taken out specifics in my code but this is what I have so far.

```
typealias COMPLETION = () -> ()

let functionOne_completion = {
    print("functionOne COMPLETED")
}

let functionTwo_completion = {
    print("functionTwo COMPLETED")
}

let functionThree_completion = {
    print("functionThree COMPLETED")
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myApp.myQueue")

    queue.sync {

        functionOne(completion: functionOne_completion)

        functionTwo(completion: functionTwo_completion)

        functionThree(completion: functionThree_completion)

    }



func functionOne(completion: @escaping COMPLETION) {

    print("functionOne STARTED")
    completion()
}

func functionTwo(completion: @escaping COMPLETION) {

    print("functionTwo STARTED")
    completion()
}

func functionThree(completion: @escaping COMPLETION) {

    print("functionThree STARTED")
    completion()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the second function on the completion of the first.

Something like:

```
func first(_ completion : @escaping()->()){

   print("first")
   completion()
}

func second(_ completion : @escaping()->()){
   print("second")
}

func third(){
   print("third")
}

override func viewDidLoad(){

   ....
   first{
     self.second{
          self.third()
     }

   }
}
```

So when your image download gets finished, inside the completion block where you get the callback of download completion, you should call your second method/block passed as argument which in turn will call your second method.

Comment: In this particular example, you don't need to define the closure as `@escaping` since it doesn't escape the function.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `DispatchGroup`

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    functionOne { dispatchGroup.leave() }
    dispatchGroup.wait() //Add reasonable timeout

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    functionTwo { dispatchGroup.leave() }
    dispatchGroup.wait()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    functionThree { dispatchGroup.leave() }
    dispatchGroup.wait()

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        //All tasks are completed
    }
}
```